# What happens after I've "saved" a level and replay it?

Tags: minigore2

After you complete a level and it's marked as saved in the level menu, I can replay it again and the title screen is shown on subsequent plays as "Night 2", "Night 3", etc. What are the differences in level plays for the different nights? Do enemies get harder? I haven't noticed anything in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enemies get increasingly difficult, as the rewards for killing them are increased by 15%. I.E. night 1 = 100% rewards, night 2 = 115%, night 3 = 130% etc.

Comment: Some confirmation of these effects would earn you a GOLD STAR

Comment: @authenticgeek Just tested this last night. The HP and rewards go up each night. It's seems like it goes up by 15% though my first thought was 20%. The purple monsters that spawn with the Dead Jester normally give 5 souls, but the second night they gave 6. The Evil Guards though, normally give 15 souls and the second night they gave 17.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters vary from level to level, but Domenik is essentially right. This is the complete list of variables affected: hp, speed, accuracy, count, money, damage.